# Approach for storing image crops

Tags: php, mysql, crop, jcrop

We have a custom built CMS which allows for image uploads. In the CMS we have implemented
[jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html). When cropping an image (with GD in PHP), we are storing the original image name and crop image name in the database (MySQL), aswel as the original image and crop image on the server.

When we need an alternate crop, we use PHP to create another crop of the cropped image (and save it to the server). Because such an image has now been processed by GD twice, the result often looks bad.

A possible use case: in the CMS we manage persons. Each person can have an image. Since persons are usually shown in portrait mode, we let the user crop in portrait. On the website this works out fine, but on the mobile website, we actually need a square image. Hence we need two crops.

Lately we've been wondering how we could improve our crop workflow. Would an approach of only storing crop coordinates in the database work on the long term? What is a common approach of dealing with crops?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mentioned that you're keeping the original uploaded image. Why not just use that as a crop source every time?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because a user could potentially crop the upper right portion from a large image. If we would create an automatic crop from the centre, the part of the original image that actually matters, would not be displayed,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this approach:

- Upload an image. Assign it an unique ID (i.e. an MD5 hash of the name).
- Let the user crop it, store only the coordinates and image name in the db
- Store the cropped image, give it a filename that is made for example out of the original file name plus the coordinates of the crop.

In this way you will be able to retrieve the cropped image only by knowing it's original name and the coordinates of the crop. In addition an exact duplicate of any crop would not be stored.

Example:

```
md5('image.jpg' . $crop->x0 . $crop->x1 . $crop->y0 . $crop->y1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How would you handle an additional crop? So if the first crop is 200 x 300. How would you handle another crop of say 200 x 200?

Comment: I would store a new crop in the db, with new image. you can't tell how the user is going to crop your image, unless you define a specific sets of available crops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what if letting the user create another crop is not an option? Like in the mentioned case where one image is used for both the regular website and the mobile website, with different image sizes?

Comment: If you can define a list of available crops and stick to it I would just automate it by taking the center portion of the image, after a rescaling to the minimum viable size for all the crops. No crop possibility for the user, just automatic ones.

Answer (score 0):

> Would an approach of only storing crop coordinates in the database work on the long term?

Not if by that you mean you would also do the cropping each time the picture is requested. That puts unnecessary load on both your server (doing the actual cropping on-the-fly each time) and on the client as well (because there will be no caching of those dynamically generated crop images, unless you implement that on top of the whole thing).

> Since persons are usually shown in portrait mode, we let the user crop in portrait. On the website this works out fine, but on the mobile website, we actually need a square image. Hence we need two crops.

Maybe a better approach would be what f.e. Facebook does in some places: Instead of cropping an image to be square server-side, the just have the client load the non-square version – and then let the client do the “cropping” by simply displaying the image as a positioned background image within a square element …

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We are currently also creating a cache-crop image on the fly. Once it's created, we don't have to create it again, so that wouldn't be a problem.

Interesting thought about hiding part of the image, but this would mean downloading more image that actually being used, which, certainly on mobile, is far from ideal.

Comment: Facebook also do on-the-fly cropping: `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/c33.33.414.414/s160x160/1012777_10151766575129009_1544383854_n.png` The `c33.33.414.414` part mean the crop coordinates, the `s160x160`  part tell it to return a `160x160` squared image. If you remove the `c33.33.414.414/s160x160/` from address you'll get the original image. They also store some default cropped versions of each image, if you replace the trailing `_n` to `_s` you'll get the default square cropped version. :)

Comment: _“Facebook also do on-the-fly cropping”_ – I didn’t say they did not use it at all. But with the image URLs you mentioned, I suppose they will at least have implemented proper HTTP caching.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I commented just to add more info about the way they crop things... :)